# In C# how do you create an instance of ILogger<T> from a Type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

As part of a unit test I'm trying to create an instance of an object that takes in a `ILogger<T>` as a parameter but I don't know the T type at compile time. Instead, I have a variable that contains the type of T.

The object I'm trying to create has a constructor that looks like this:

```cs
public class PersonRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger<PersonRepository> logger;

    public PersonRepository(ILogger<PersonRepository> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

How can I create an instance of `ILogger<T>` from a `Type` please?

I've tried doing this as the most obvious solution but it creates an `ILogger` rather than an `ILogger<PersonRepository>`.

```cs
var t = typeof(PersonRepository);
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(t);
var personRepository = Activator.CreateInstance(t, logger); // This line fails as logger is an ILogger instead of an ILogger<PersonRepository>
```

I've also got access to Moq to create instances if that helps provide more options here.

Comment: Do you want to create specific class instance that implement `ILogger` or you want to create a mock for `ILogger`?

Comment: "it creates an ILogger rather than an ILogger<PersonRepository>" I think you are right that the implicitly typed variable that holds the return value will be typed (by the compiler) as an `ILogger`. But that doesn't mean the object itself isn't an `ILogger<PersonRepository>`. Have you checked the runtime type using `GetType()`?

Comment: In response to all comments I've added some additional code to the question that I think might help.
Yes, I am specifically wanting an ILogger<PersonRepository> in this case, not an ILogger as the Activator.CreateInstance() call can't find a constructor for it because the logger is a different type than expected.
I've just spent more time investigating @KlausGütter's answer and I've found a solution that works for me :)